# Sorting Dict throws an error - python

Tags: python

I am learning python and trying to sort dicts in the simplest way and its throwing errors

```
d = {'a':10,'b':1,'c':22}
print (d.items())

t = d.items()
t.sort()
print (t)
```

And it throws me the below error

```
dict_items([('b', 1), ('a', 10), ('c', 22)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bash/Downloads/n.py", line 5, in <module>
    t.sort()
AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Yes, I googled and stackoverflow did not give the results I am looking for so it would be great if you dont down vote this question and give an answer if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dict doesn't have a `sort` attribute. You can sort it by keys using `sorted`:

```
for key in sorted(d.iterkeys()):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, d[key]))
```

Comment: I'd also note that `sorted()` can be used with dict_item objects, so all the asker really needed to do with his code was change `t.sort()` to `t = sorted(t)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the thing, your original code works in python 2.x:

```
d = {'a': 10, 'b': 1, 'c': 22}
print(d.items())

t = d.items()
t.sort()
print(t)
```

Because d.items() returns a `<type 'list'>` class, but not with python 3.x, with python 3.x it returns `<class 'dict_items'>`, which doesn't have the sort method, so a possible workaround would be doing like this:

```
d = {'a': 10, 'b': 1, 'c': 22}

t = list(d.items())
print(t)
t.sort()
print(t)
```

As you can see, casting d.items() to list will allow you to use [list.sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)